# Windows mount Azure File share with access to a single share

Tags: azure, azure-storage-files, azure-files

I was wondering if it is possible to mount a drive in Windows that is from an Azure file share, and the user only has access to that specific share.  I would think creating a SAS signature for the share could work, but I have only seen examples of mounting a share using the Storage account key (and that provides access to all shares)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** To mount an Azure file share, you will need the primary (or secondary) storage key. ***SAS keys are not currently supported for mounting***.

To use an Azure file share with Windows, you must either mount it, which means assigning it a **drive letter** or **mount point path**, or access it via its **UNC path**.

For more details, refer "[Using an Azure file share with Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#using-an-azure-file-share-with-windows)".

Comment: Ok thanks.  Any way to add that on a roadmap.  It would be a nice feature so I could provide a specific share to specific users

Comment: You may leave your feedback here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/14498352-allow-azure-files-shares-to-be-mounted-using-sas-s